# NS2 Vs Opnet Vs GloMoSim

Tags: ns2, glomosim

I am planning to implement a concept in MANET(Mobile Ad hoc network) and I am trying to simulate the same please suggest a good simulator . I am not sure which one would be ease of use and which one is good in simulation as I am doing this for the first time. Please suggest a good one form the list below,

**NS2 or
or Opnet or
GloMoSim**

if you have any more suggestions please do let me know.

Many thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 1):

I am using glomosim to configure my protocol "authenticated routing protocol for ad hoc networks". Because from the research paper when i get to know about the protocol it was implemented in Glomosim itself. So i wanna improve the performance of it.
The moral of the story is that the selection simulator is depends upon what exactly you want to do in MANETs. it depends upon your particular problem area space. There is one more simulator. The name is ONE simulator for such ad hoc networks. i can provide you the help if you need in configuring the simulator